# JQuery set an element at the middle of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, positioning

Hi I have some elements like these:

```
<div id="one">content</div>
<div id="two">content</div>
```

and a corrispondent number of elements (without any parent, they are just after the body tag) that have:

```
position: absolute;
```

and with an id like that:

```
id="helper-one" refers to id="one"
```

Now i want to place the second group of elements exactly at the middle (vertical and horizontal) of referred elements, how can i do that?

I've tried with offset:

```
    var one_offset = $("#one").offset();

    $("#helper-one").offset({ top: one_offset.top, right: one_offset.right, left:one_offset.left, bottom: one_offset.bottom})
```

but it set position only for top and left positionating the helper at the top-left corner of the element and not at its center

Comment: You have to compute the position of the helper based not only on the position of the element, but also with the width and height of both the element and the helper. (Something like helper.top = elmt.top + (elmt.height - helper.height)/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.fn.center = function (obj) {
  var loc = obj.offset();
  this.css("top",(obj.outerHeight() - this.outerHeight()) / 2 + loc.top + 'px');
  this.css("left",(obj.outerWidth() - this.outerWidth())  / 2 + loc.left+ 'px');
  return this;
}
```

Call as `$("#helper-one").center($("#one"));`

ps: you may even skip obj argument by parsing the id of the original element

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
  var obj = $('#' + this.attr('id').split('-')[1]), loc = obj.offset();
  this.css("top",(obj.outerHeight() - this.outerHeight()) / 2 + loc.top + 'px');
  this.css("left",(obj.outerWidth() - this.outerWidth())  / 2 + loc.left+ 'px');
  return this;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#helper-one").center();       
});
```

Comment: there was some errors, this works for me   this.css("top",(loc.top + obj.outerHeight() / 2 - this.outerHeight() / 2 + 'px'));
  this.css("left",(loc.left + obj.outerWidth() / 2 - this.outerWidth() / 2 + 'px'));

Comment: @Matteo Pagliazzi  I checked the script - it was working without any problem. `this works for me` you wrote the same thing, just opened parenthesizes.

Comment: @Matteo Pagliazzi   Sorry, I've tested it on a square divs :))